# ByDeafult event for combobox value

Tags: extjs, extjs6

I have some requirment which happen after the selecting from dropdown in combobox. But In some cases I getting default value. So for that which even i have to fier.

`onchange` and `onselect` is working when I select from the dropdown. But in my case I need event when Combo value is by default select.

Answer (score 1):

So the change events don't fire when field's are created with a value so you will either have to run your post-change code after the init code (i.e. initComponent, constructor or render) or you could override the `initValue` method of the component and prevent it suspending those events on the initial value set.

Whether that's a good idea I'll leave up to you to decide!

Check out this [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/30mq) and the source file for the [original code](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/classic/src/Field.js.html#Ext.form.field.Field-method-initValue)